# stitched 360 video taken using Samsung Gear 360 dark in aframe <a-scene> <a-assets>

Tags: web, aframe, webvr

I used the exact same code sample used on aframevr/aframe 360-video [example](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.6.0/examples/boilerplate/360-video/index.html).

All I changed was the source URL. But the only thing we see is a dark page, not the 360 video we shot with our Samsung Gear 360.

```
<a-scene>
   <a-assets>
     <video id="video" src="http://siteurl.net/vrvid/cattle.mp4"
           autoplay loop crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
   </a-assets>

   <a-videosphere src="#video" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Without the actual video, this is hard to debug. If that URL happens to be your actual video URL then the video is no longer available. I get redirected to siteurl.net.